# Wish to design new integral symbol with infinity symbol through it

Tags: symbols

Would you guys help me design an integral symbol with the `\infty` symbol inscribed through it and aligned correctly with the slant of the integral symbol?  I tried using

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\loopint}{\begingroup \displaystyle \unitlength 1pt
 \int\mkern-8.9mu\begin{picture}(0,3)\put(-4.7,3){$\circ$}\end{picture}
 \hspace{-5.3pt}\raisebox{-1pt}{\displaystyle$\circ$}\mkern2mu\endgroup}
```

as you can see, rather than the infinity symbol, it just uses two circles which don't look professional in my opinion and also my latex editor give me an error that I have a missing `$` in it which I cannot determine where.

Comment: Thanks for providing what you had attemtped, but please keep in mind that instead of code snippets, it is _always_ best to compose a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\Xint` defined below to build your own integral signs.  Using `\Xint{\infty}` will place `\infty` on the integral sign. If you want a rotated symbol you can use `\rotatebox` from the `graphicx` package which is what the `\Rinfty` does. So using `\Xint{\Rinfty}` generates the second symbol:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\Xint#1{\mathchoice%
{\XXint\displaystyle\textstyle{#1}}% 
{\XXint\textstyle\scriptstyle{#1}}% 
{\XXint\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}% 
{\XXint\scriptscriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}% 
\!\int}%
\def\XXint#1#2#3{{\setbox0=\hbox{$#1{#2#3}{\int}$}%
\vcenter{\hbox{$#2#3$}}\kern-.5\wd0}}%

\newcommand{\Rinfty}{\rotatebox{77}{$\infty$}\hspace{0.6em}}%

\begin{document}
\[ \Xint{\infty} f(x) \qquad \Xint{\Rinfty} f(x)\]
\end{document}
```

---

As pointed out by AlanMunn, the original code is due to Donald Aresneau (posted in comp.text.tex in 1991) and appears in the TeX FAQ and also in Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols Guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (which credits the FAQ), and in Herbert Voss's  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

Comment: Ok, I understand the first post and will include a complet document the next time. However, that's not how I wish the infinity symbol to be aligned rather I'd like it aligned vertical with the same slant as the integral sign.  Maybe I can study the code above however and get it rotated correctly.

Comment: @Jack: So you want the `\infty` rotated?

Comment: Also, note if I just use an "8" in the code above, the font has a smaller top circle than the bottom circle which doesn't look professional when it's through the integral sign and also using the code above, it's not aligned perfectly with the slant of the integral sign.

Comment: Yes, I'd like it rotated say, from the symbol here, around 85 degrees so that it's aligned perfectly with the integral sign.

Comment: @Jake: Have provided an updated solution which also provides a version that places the rotated symbol.

Comment: Peter, your \rotatebox command I notice works only when I compile a PDF document.  When I compile a DVI document, which is what I use when I'm writing a paper, the infinity sign is not rotated.  Is there something I'm not setting up properly for this to happen?

Comment: @Jake: I do not think you should have to anything different, but you should post a new question as we like to keep one question per post.

Comment: @Jake: DVI cannot show rotations, use the PDF viewer

Comment: Ok.  Thanks guys.  I have it just where I want it now in the PDF viewer.

Answer (score 5):

if you need it only in one size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathrlap{\mkern3mu\infty}\int f(x)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]