# Create Pole/Point Integral Symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I want to create the following shaped integrals found in the [unicode-math package symbols list](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf):

[image]

I created my own package a while ago for defining some symbols/shortcuts, and I want to *recreate* these symbols (not simply import them from unicode-math because I want them to match the MinionPro font that I use for math, and since I want integrals to be upright (which I defined in my package as `\rint`) and created symbols not already in MinionPro for math I don't want to have to re-do all my previous work).

There is a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36149/wish-to-design-new-integral-symbol-with-infinity-symbol-through-it) that asks something similar, but it's only for imposing a symbol on an integral. In other words, the integral runs through the symbol and it overlaps. I already know how to do this but as you can see, the integrals I want here stop where the point symbol is entered (i.e. it doesn't intersect with whatever symbol is in the middle).

MinionPro (specifically, `MnSymbolF1`) already has the symbol in the middle of the last integral shown, but I'm also not sure if the middle two integrals use different symbols or simply shift/resize that symbol somehow. `MnSymbolF1` also has a symbol *like* the one used in the first integral, but I guess shifted/flipped and possibly resized somehow.

Thus, how can I **create** these symbols by myself, in a way that's compatible with LuaTeX (or at least XeTeX)?

Comment: Why don't you just use `unicode-math`, if you already use Xe/LuaLatex?

Comment: @HenriMenke as I mentioned in the first paragraph, I want the integrals to match the MinionPro font that I use for math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Remarks

Here is a solution with TikZ, but beware!

- All the lengths are adjusted by manual finetuning, if you change the font, you will have to **readjust everything**
- You can't use normal limits (like `\int_0^1`) with this solution, but you have the possibility to pass the limits as optional arguments, see MWE.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[minionint,mathlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner sep=\pgflinewidth}
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\rppolint[1][]{\mathpalette\@rppolint{#1}}
\newcommand\@rppolint[2]{
  \mathop{
    \tikz[baseline=(int.base),every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]{
      \node (int) at (0,0) {%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\int$}%
        \hbox to \wd0{$#1\int#2$\hss}
      };
      \fill[white] (-2.5pt+.5\pgflinewidth,-2.5pt+.5\pgflinewidth) rectangle (2.5pt-.5\pgflinewidth,2.5pt-.5\pgflinewidth);
      \draw (0,2.5pt) -| (2.5pt,-2.5pt) -- (-0.8pt,-2.5pt);
      \node[dot] at (0,0) {};
    }
  }\nolimits
}
\newcommand\scpolint[1][]{\mathpalette\@scpolint{#1}}
\newcommand\@scpolint[2]{
  \mathop{
    \tikz[baseline=(int.base),every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]{
      \node (int) at (0,0) {%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\int$}%
        \hbox to \wd0{$#1\int#2$\hss}
      };
      \fill[white] (0,0) circle (2.5pt-.5\pgflinewidth);
      \draw (85:2.5pt) arc (85:-110:2.5pt);
      \node[dot] at (0,0) {};
    }
  }\nolimits
}
\newcommand\npolint[1][]{\mathpalette\@npolint{#1}}
\newcommand\@npolint[2]{
  \mathop{
    \tikz[baseline=(int.base),every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]{
      \node (int) at (0,0) {%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\int$}%
        \hbox to \wd0{$#1\int#2$\hss}
      };
      \begin{scope}[shift={(1.1pt,0)}]
        \fill[white] (0,0) circle (2.5pt-.5\pgflinewidth);
        \draw (110:2.5pt) arc (110:-130:2.5pt);
        \node[dot] at (0,0) {};
      \end{scope}
    }
  }\nolimits
}
\newcommand\pointint[1][]{\mathpalette\@pointint{#1}}
\newcommand\@pointint[2]{
  \mathop{
    \tikz[baseline=(int.base),every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]{
      \node (int) at (0,0) {%
        \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\int$}%
        \hbox to \wd0{$#1\int#2$\hss}
      };
      \filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.5pt-.5\pgflinewidth);
      \node[dot] at (0,0) {};
    }
  }\nolimits
}
\begin{document}
$
\displaystyle \rppolint[_0^1]
\textstyle    \rppolint[_0^1]
\displaystyle \scpolint[_0^1]
\textstyle    \scpolint[_0^1]
\displaystyle \npolint[_0^1]
\textstyle    \npolint[_0^1]
\displaystyle \pointint[_0^1]
\textstyle    \pointint[_0^1]
$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is a great answer, I just wish the middle part (the circles/squares) would also resize when the integral is in different scales, but I think (hope) I can figure that out on my own? Anyways I really appreciate the effort you put into this, thank you!

Comment: @Alborz Use a unit that scales with text or math like `ex` or `em`. I'm not sure if `mu` also scales.